# How do I un-register user agent with the RingCentral Web Phone Client Library?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, ringcentral

I can see that I must register a SIP Device using `/restapi/v1.0/client-info/sip-provision` endpoint based on this API resource: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/SipDeviceRegistration.html

Based on the[RingCentral Web Phone Client Library](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-web-phone), and using the  [RingCentral JS-SDK](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js) I am able to provision the SIP device:

```js
// Setup RingCentral
var RC = require('ringcentral');
var sdk = new RC({
    server: process.env.RC_SERVER,
    appKey: process.env.RC_APP_KEY,
    appSecret: process.env.RC_APP_SECRET 
});

var platform = sdk.platform();

// Login
platform
    .login({
        username: process.env.RC_USERNAME,
        extension: process.env.RC_EXTENSION,
        password: process.env.RC_PASSWORD 
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
        console.error('RC LOGIN ERROR: ', e);
        throw e;
    });

// SIP Provision
platform
            .post('/client-info/sip-provision', {
                sipInfo: [{transport: 'WSS'}]
            })
            .then(function(res) {
                io.emit('sipProvisionResponse', res.json());
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                console.error(e);
                throw e;
            });
```

Once the SIP-provisioning for the device is done, I then use that information to instantiate the WebPhone

```js
var webPhone;
var rcSipProvision; // Is set to result of request to /restapi/v1.0/client-info/sip-provision
rcSipProvision = data.sipInfo[0] || data.sipInfo;;
//console.log('RingCentral: ', RingCentral);
webPhone = new RingCentral.WebPhone(data, {
  logLevel:1,
  audioHelper: {
    enabled: true, // enables audio feedback when phone is ringing or making call
    incoming: '/audio/incoming.ogg', // path to audio file for incoming call
    outgoing: '/audio/outgoing.ogg' // path to audio file for outgoing call
  }
});
$callButton.removeAttr('disabled');

webPhone.userAgent.on('invite', onInvite);
webPhone.userAgent.on('connecting', onConnecting);
webPhone.userAgent.on('connected', onConnected);
webPhone.userAgent.on('disconnected', onDisconnected);
webPhone.userAgent.on('registered', onRegistered);
webPhone.userAgent.on('unregistered', onUnregistered);
webPhone.userAgent.on('registrationFailed', onRegistrationFailed);
webPhone.userAgent.on('message', onMessage);
```

Using the above I am able to use the web phone client library to invite others to calls using WebRTC with [webPhone.userAgent.invite](https://github.com/bdeanindy/ringcentral-webrtc-crm-demo/blob/97fdbdb9803ab17eb0aa80559c9be47a752d9759/public/javascripts/rcDemoApp.js#L417-L429). What if a user closes the browser and terminates the session? How do I handle making sure my application updates RingCentral by terminating the SIP Provision and un-registering the user agent?

I do not see how to un-register a user agent referenced in the [RingCentral Web Phone Client Library](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-web-phone/blob/master/src/ringcentral-web-phone.js#L169-L175) since this is included in the creation of the WebPhone from either the [RingCentral Web Phone Client Library](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-web-phone), the [RingCentral JS SDK](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js), or the [RignCentral API Reference for SIP Device Registration](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/SipDeviceRegistration.html).

I do not see that the WebPhone exposes the ability to unregister the user agent, and I am trying to figure out how to do this properly.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RingCentral Web Phone is a custom wrapper of SIP.JS, so in order to unregister you just need to call SIP.JS's method: http://sipjs.com/api/0.7.0/ua/#unregisteroptions

In your case it would be `webPhone.userAgent.unregister`.

Comment: Thanks DFuse, I will try this and report results.

Would you like me to create an issue to update the documentation in the Github issue tracker for the [RingCentral Web Phone Client Library](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-web-phone/issues), or would you like to create the issue?

Comment: Worked as expected. Thank you.